# parallel::forkmanager....how to pass 2 variables on exit

Tags: perl, fork, pipe

I am using Parallel::ForkManager to pass a few variables from the children to the parent. I'm able to pass $var...how do I pass more? (thanks again to Hobbs for helping me get this far)

```
use Parallel::ForkManager;

my $pm=new Parallel::ForkManager(10); 
my(@cusips,@bad);
$pm->run_on_finish(sub{
my($pid,$exit_code,$ident,$exit_signal,$core_dump,$var,$v)=@_;
print "pid: ".$pid."\n";
print " first: ".${$var}."\n"; 
print " second: ".${$v}."\n";   
});


for(1..3){

$pm->start and next; # do the fork 
my $var=rand();
my $v=rand();

$pm->finish(0,\$var,\$v); # do the exit in the child process 
}


$pm->wait_all_children;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There can be only one :)

Pass an array reference:

```
$pm->finish(0, [ $var, $v ]);
```

or a hash reference:

```
$pm->finish(0, { 'var' => $var, 'v' => $v });
```

And:

```
$pm->run_on_finish(sub{
    my ($pid,$exit_code,$ident,$exit_signal,$core_dump,$data)=@_;
    print "pid: ".$pid."\n";
    print " first: ".$data->[0]."\n"; 
    print " second: ".$data->[1]."\n";   
});
```

or

```
$pm->run_on_finish(sub{
    my ($pid,$exit_code,$ident,$exit_signal,$core_dump,$data)=@_;
    print "pid: ".$pid."\n";
    print " first: ".$data->{'var'}."\n"; 
    print " second: ".$data->{'v'}."\n";   
});
```

Comment: How do I then access the variables from the run_on_finish subroutine?

Comment: @user522962, if you remove all those unneeded "\", the *values* can be accessed using `my $resp = $_[5]; my ($var, $v) = @$resp; ... $var ... $v ...` and `my $resp = $_[5]; ... $resp->{var} ... $resp->{v} ...` respectively.

Comment: @ysth, You shouldn't be creating references to the scalars. The OP did that since the Storable requires a reference, but `[]` and `{}` already return a reference.

Comment: updated.  @ikegami: the only reason for the references I could see would be to avoid an extra copy being made in the child before serialization.  Unlikely to actually be significant, but I left it in anyway.

Comment: Ah, I thought P::FM supported non-references too; removing them.